# buttons on wxWidgets

Tags: c++, user-interface, button, wxwidgets

I am programming a GUI with wxWidgets. I got a button to open a serial port and receive data. In there is a `while(1)` loop to constantly receive the data.

Now I want to do a "Disconnect" button to stop receiving.

Is there an event handler or a callback function to interrupt the while and jump out of the loop from the first button, when I press another button?

Answer (score 3):

A wxButton sends a message when it is clicked. Create a handler for this message where you do your "interrruption".

Now, a loop can be only exited from its inner guts. I mean, inside the loop you should check a flag, and depending on the value of this flag continue or exit.

My advice is that you create a **worker thread**. When the button "connect" is clicked then you create the thread that receives data.

This thread checks an extern flag and finishes depending on the value of the flag.

The "disconnect" button click-handler just sets that extern flag to a value that makes the thread exits when it checks that flag.

Take a look at the *thread sample* provided with wxWidgets sources.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply!

Comment: How does that worker thread look like? I tried couple of things now but unfortunatelly i did not manage to get it right yet.

Comment: @MSol That's meat for another question, not more comments here. You can start with the *thread* sample in wxWidgets distribution, or use `std::thread` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `while(1)` loop in the callback function for "button pressed", you will hang the UI.  Callback functions must return quickly.

The quickest solution is to put the `while(1)` loop into a worker thread.  That way your GUI won't hang.

The next problem is how to *stop* the loop.  That's quite easy.  Change the loop into:

```
while (keep_going.load()) {
    ....
```

where `keep_going` is of type `std::atomic_bool`.  Then your "stop" button just calls `keep_going.store(false)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply!

Comment: It says actomic_bool is not a member of std

Comment: You will need `#include <atomic>`, and you will need to spell it `atomic` rather than `actomic` (but I guess the latter is actually a typo :-) ).  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: i still got a problem with this, i used the atomic_bool keep_going variable but when i use the: 

while(keep_going.load()){...} it never jumps into my while

Comment: You did initialize `keep_going` to `true` didn't you?  Otherwise it is going to use default initialization for a `bool` ... which is `false`.

Comment: yes i did that,

std::atomic_bool keep_going(true);

and then there is my while as you said 

while(keep_going.load())
{
....
}

which now also works, but the 

keep_going.store(false);

unfortunatelly does not interrupt my while loop

Comment: @MSol: And the `while` loop is on a different thread to the command handler?  That would just be weird.  I think you need to write a separate question for that, with a [mcve]

Comment: Ich habe gerade gesehen Sie kommen auch aus Deutschland :)
Leider habe ich noch nie zuvor mit threads bzw worker threads gearbeitet, daher liegt das Problem wohl eher an der Programmierung des Threads
Gibt es denn ein Beispiel für einen worker thread um sich da etwas einzulesen?

Comment: @MSol : Ich *leben* in Deutschland, aber nur seit 2016.  Ich bin Englander (bis 2024 und dann ich kann deutsche Bürger werden).  The second example in the [QThread documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qthread.html) looks pretty good to me.